# How can I disable search suggestions for Safari 6?

Tags: macos, safari

I have a lot of bookmarks, and I'm used to navigating by typing in the first few letters of each bookmark and using the arrow keys to select the correct one. In Safari 6, however, only the first two results are bookmarks, then there are around 7 search suggestions, and then the rest of my bookmarks. Is there any way to disable these search suggestions?

Comment: Would be great if it worked as it should. Using Safari 6.0.2 under Lion, the check box makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Privacy** tab of Safari preferences, check the box to **Prevent search engine from providing suggestions**.

[image]

Comment: Wow... That was pretty obvious. Can't believe I missed that!